# Cannot reach specific public IP

Tags: linux, networking, internet, nat

My server (runs on Ubuntu 12.04) is behind a NAT and has to access a specific service that has a public IP address (`64.*.*.*`).

The problem is that I cannot reach that specific public IP (all other IP addresses for the same service work; the domain has several IP addresses assigned to it).
The same IP address can be reached from another identical environment. The NAT server (through which I pass) can also access it.

Tcpdump on my server shows only SYN packages, while on the NAT does not show any traffic comming from my server. 
The IP is not blocked by iptables on the NAT server. 
Another IP for the same service works fine.

Scheme:

My Server -> My NAT -> (Unreachable) Public IP

Routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.2.200      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.10.0.0        10.10.2.1        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.10.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.10.9.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

IP Address of eth0: 10.10.2.51

I discovered (by comparing the MAC addresses in tcpdumps and looking in the arp table) that instead of going towards my default gateway, the server tries to establish the connection through 10.10.2.1 (but only for that public IP, `64.*.*.*`), which is puzzling me.

Comment: Share your routing table and your NIC configuration. Verify that packets take the correct interface when leaving your server.

Comment: What is the unreachable public IP?

Comment: That IP is unreachable only from my server (the one in question; the other ones work perfectly). It's address should not matter.

Comment: @Mihai For us to understand the route your server is sending the connection along, we need to know what IP you're trying to access. For example, if it's within `10.10.0.*`, then it'll be routed through `10.10.2.1`. For the reasons you've listed, it's probably a routing issue on your server, and the address we're trying to reach matters very much for figuring this out.

Comment: @Darth: If the target address is within 10.10.0.*, then I would hope that the OP would not so emphatically call it a “public IP address.”  Still, …

Comment: @Mihai: Are you addressing the external service by a domain name?  Are you _sure_ that your server is trying to go to the IP address that you think it is trying to go to?  I.e., is the destination IP address of the SYN packets correct?  What happens if you use the raw, numeric IP address?

Comment: @DarthAndroid: The IP, as I updated my post, is very public and the problem seems to be beneath the routing table and other visible configurations, somewhere in some caching for the network routing (initially, 1 week ago, the default gateway was 10.10.2.1).

Comment: @Mihai: as the last comment implies, there's a cached routing table entry somewhere. The `route` command doesn't actually tell you everything the kernel will do; try `ip route get to 64.1.1.1` (insert correct address) to confirm what it thinks it's doing, `ip route show table cache` to get the current cache contents; `man ip` for more details on that (you'll probably end up calling `ip route flush <something>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem. Unfortunately, I don't know which of the two things I did solved it.

First I added one more interface from a different subnet (10.10.8.51), changed the NAT server IP address (10.10.8.200) and sent all the default traffic through that interface.

Secondly, I discovered that the NAT server did ICMP redirect so I disabled the accepting of redirects. I actually think that this caused my problem, but I did not have time to test it on the staging env.

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth2.accept_redirects = 0
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth2.send_redirects = 0

# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth2.accept_redirects = 0
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth2.send_redirects = 0
```